# Deactivation of microsoft azure

Tags: azure, azure-billing

I don't active subscription on microsoft azure. I just signed in with my microsoft ID. I want to permanently delete my account so that I don't end up paying bills. So how can I completely deactivate?

PS: I don't have any active subscription on azure account.

Comment: If you don't have an Azure Subscription, you won't be charged. To delete your Microsoft Account, login into your account and request account deletion from there.

Comment: I don't think this is an appropiate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: You could also raise a free billing ticket for help on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Answer (score 0):

Clean up Subscription. than mean delete all resource that you have created. So that you can avoid the further billing.

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-cancel-azure-subscription) you find the step to cancel the subscription.

Comment: I haven't created any resource, I don't have any subscription active. I just signed with the microsoft account credentials. So what steps should I follow?

Comment: No worries on Microsoft Account you won't get any bills. it just Mail account. if you want Delete account follow this Link. https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12412/microsoft-account-how-to-close-account

Comment: Sir I know that but I have used my credentials and they re-directed me to azure homepage.